# in Java get the results from two blocks executing in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-integration, rx-java

Researching this has been a little difficult due to I'm not precisely sure how the question should be worded. Here is some pseudo code summarizing my goal.

```
public class TestService {
    Object someBigMehtod(String A, Integer I) {
        {  //block A 
            //do some long database read
        }
        { //block B
            //do another long database read at the same time as block B
        }
        {  //block C
            //get in this block when both A & B are complete
            //and access result returned or pushed from A & B
            //to build up some data object to push out to a class that called
            //this service or has subscribed to it
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking I can use RxJava or Spring Integration to accomplish this or maybe just instantiating multiple threads and running them. Just the layout of it though makes me think Rx has the solution because I am thinking data is pushed to block C. Thanks in advance for any advice you might have.

Comment: @Ankur If you have a solution in mind post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). In particular, its [`thenCombine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, which waits for two tasks to complete.

```
CompletableFuture<A> fa = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // do some long database read
    return a;
});

CompletableFuture<B> fb = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // do another long database read
    return b;
});

CompletableFuture<C> fc = fa.thenCombine(fb, (a, b) -> {
    // use a and b to build object c
    return c;
});

return fc.join();
```

These methods will all execute on the [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--). You can control where they run if you pass in optional [`Executor`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Zip** operator from **Rxjava**. This operator can run in parallel multiple process and then zip the results.

Some docu http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

And here an example of how works https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/combining/ObservableZip.java

Answer (score 0):

For now I just went with John's suggestion. This is getting the desired effect. I mix in RxJava1 and RxJava2 syntax a bit which is probably poor practice. Looks like I have some reading cut out for me on java.util.concurrent package . Time permitting I would like to do the zip solution.

```
@Test
public void myBigFunction(){
    System.out.println("starting ");
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> fa =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () ->
        {  //block A
            //do some long database read
            try {

                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("part A");
                return asList(new String[] {"abc","def"});
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    );

    CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> fb =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () ->
            {  //block B
                //do some long database read
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                    System.out.println("Part B");
                    return asList(new Integer[] {123,456});
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
    );

    CompletableFuture<List<String>> fc = fa.thenCombine(fb,(a,b) ->{
        //block C
        //get in this block when both A & B are complete
        int sum = b.stream().mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).sum();
        return a.stream().map(new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(String s) {
                return s+sum;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
    System.out.println(fc.join());
}
```

It does only take 6 seconds to run.